# How do I refine the results of an importXML function?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a spreadsheet to try and help track peoples heart of azeroth levels, and I've got my cell set as

```
=IMPORTXML("https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-gb/character/Zenedar/Father","//*[@class='GameIcon-level']")
```

however it seems to return the number 36 twice, once in the cell I want and another in the cell below, how do I refine this to a single cell of '36'

Comment: Could you share the actual XML instead of URL?

Comment: @Joshua Lines Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

How about these modifications? In this modification, it adds the parent node.

#### Modified formula 1:

When you want to retrieve 1st value of 2 values, you can use this.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='CharacterProfile-item']//*[@class='GameIcon-level']")
```

#### Modified formula 2:

When you want to retrieve 2nd value of 2 values, you can use this.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='List-item']//*[@class='GameIcon-level']")
```

#### Note:

- You can also use `div[@class='GameIcon-level']` instead of `*[@class='GameIcon-level']`.